# SlideToggle open/closes permanently

Tags: jquery, css

i've the following problem: A menu should open/close on mobile device, so i did an if-query, if the browser-width is smaller than size x and then the script should appear, so it looks like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  var mobilewidth = $(window).width();
  if(mobilewidth < 873 ) {
    $(".mod_customcatalogfilter h2").click(function() {
      $(".filterform").slideToggle();
    });
  } else {
    $(".filterform").removeAttr("style");
  }
});
```

It works, but the `.filterform` bounces up and down and closes then.

Here you can see it in action: http://codepen.io/Sukrams/pen/WwjejP

Does anybody has any idea why it behaves so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each time you resize the window, a new click event listener is created, therefore each time you click the event listeners triggered x times ( as much times as you have resized the window under 873 ). so basically youre solution is not create the event listener click more then once.

one option is -

```
var isEventListenerCreated = false;
$(window).resize(function() { 

    var mobilewidth = $(window).width();

    if(mobilewidth < 873 && isEventListenerCreated === false) {
       isEventListenerCreated = true;
        $(".mod_customcatalogfilter h2").click(function() {
            $(".filterform").slideToggle();
        });
    } else {
        $(".filterform").removeAttr("style");
    }
    });
```

another option is to unbind the event listener each time the window resizes bigger than 873.

Comment: I'm using your solution but find now one new problem: It doesn't appears on my smartphone (iphone 6) when the page is loaded, i have to scroll down, so that the size of the browser is resized.

Can it be fixed, so that it will appear, when the page is loaded, because the problem is, users can just click the navigation, when they scrolled down the page.

Comment: Just use the same function you used in the resize event when then screen is loaded and that should do the trick

Comment: my second solution would'nt even cause this problem, since I bind the event beforhand and not on reisze. Yet you still accept his answer two days later.

Answer (score 1):

You bind the event each time on resize. It does not override the existing actionListener, but adds another to it. Fast and unperfomant solution would be to unbind() the event each time.

```
if(mobilewidth < 873 ) {
    $(".mod_customcatalogfilter h2").unbind();
    $(".mod_customcatalogfilter h2").click(function() {
        $(".filterform").slideToggle();
    });
} else {
    $(".mod_customcatalogfilter h2").unbind();
    $(".filterform").removeAttr("style");
}
```

Much better and more performant would be to cache the variables beforehand and only bind the event once.

```
var $filter = $(".mod_customcatalogfilter h2");
var mobilewidth = $(window).width();
$filter.on('click', function() {
    if (mobilewidth < 873) {
      $(".filterform").slideToggle();
    } else {
      $(".filterform").removeAttr("style");
    }
});
$(window).resize(function() {
  mobilewidth = $(window).width();
});
```